# Build Openlayers 3 on Windows

Tags: openlayers-2, windows, openlayers

On GitHub is a wonderful installation instructions, but most users GitHub, use Linux, it's not worked on Windows....
https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/wiki/Developer-Guide

How can I build OpenLayers 3 on Windows?

Can't install Pystache

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Openlayers\pystache-0.5.3\setup.py", line 111, in <module>
    import setuptools as dist
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

And Closure Linter

```
Warning (from warnings module):

     File "C:\Openlayers\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 267
        warnings.warn(msg)
    UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this just a couple of days ago. The error that you are getting doesn't have anything to do specifically with OL3.

The error that you are facing, has to do with setup tools not being installed.

I have found that the easiest way to get this done, is to download [ez_setup.py](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) and install it from there.

To recap, you need to do this:

1. Download the OpenLayers Code.
2. Install Python if you don't have it installed.
3. Install Setup tools from ez_setup.py
4. Install Pystache
5. Install [RegEx](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#regex)
6. Finally build OL3 by running `build.py` in the OL3 directory

Comment: Need for build OL3 phantom.js, node.js and plovr? And why should they?

Comment: Those are needed for the tests, not for the build.

Comment: Failed to install ez_setup.py or it does not matter?`Extracting in c:\users\2e78~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpxc2sdu
Now working in c:\users\2e78~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpxc2sdu\setuptools-3.4.4
Installing Setuptools
Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.`

Comment: @jonh: Yes, it needs to be installed correctly; Only after that can you proceed. What's the python version that you are using?

Comment: I use Python 2.7.6. I think that maybe conflict with Python from ArcGIS. But i install from https://www.python.org/download/

Comment: Maybe it's important i use Windows 8

Comment: Do you have the 32bit or the 64 bit version of Python installed? What output do you get when you run `python.exe` on the command line?

Comment: 64 bit. `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'python' is not defined >>>`

Comment: Maybe install newest version of Pyhton?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14034/discussion-between-devdatta-tengshe-and-jonh)

Comment: I try to install on Windows 7 and again i can't install Pystache

Comment: Problem in Pystache and i don't know how 'right' install this tool

Comment: I install all modules but build no worked on Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing Linux specific in these installation instructions as far as I can see. They should work the same in a windows command shell. Only make sure, that you've installed all the dependencies.

After you've installed all dependencies you should be able to use `build.cmd` on your windows system.

What exactly is not working on your system?

Comment: I can't install Python extra modules see this blog: http://www.spatially-oriented.com/blog/2013/12/13/building-openlayers-3-on-windows/